# Entity Framework Core - realtion between two tables without using primary key

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to write Console application in dotnet core 2.1 with EFCore.Postgres 2.1.2.

I have two tables in existing Database. Every table has it's own Primary key, but these tables should be related via another field - UserId

[image: db]

My models:

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public int UserAddressId {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}

    public virtual UserDetails UserDetails {get;set;}
}

public class UserDetails
{
    public int UserDetailId {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

How Can I 'Teach' Entityframework to join these tables wia UserId?
I would like to use them like below

```
using (var MyDb = new GraffitiDbContext())
{
    var query = MyDb.UserAddress              
        .Include(row => row.UserDetails);

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.Writeline(item.UserDetails.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you define such relationship in postgres? What are the restrictions? Can there be multiple `UserAddress` or `UserDetails` with the same `UserId`? Can there be no `UserAddress` for `UserDetails` with a speific `UserId` and vice versa?

Comment: It's not possible in general if the `UserId` is not unique in one of the tables. Also don't you have `User` table where `UserId` is a PK, so these 2 tables relate indirectly through it?

Comment: In postgres there is a table with UserId as a PK, and these two tables has FK. but in my console app I don't need data from that table. If you mind strict relationship between UserAddres and UserDetails - there isn't such a relationship. 
It's one to one relation. Assume that I don't need UserDetails, if there is no UserAddress for specyfied UserId.
In both tables UserId is unique.

Comment: You may try mapping `UserId` in both entities as [alternate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) and try to map the one-to-one relationship with `modelBuilder.Entity<UserAddress>().HasOne(e => e.UserDetails).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey<UserAddress>(e => e.UserId).HasForeignKey<UserDetails>(e => e.UserId)`. It might eventually work, but I personally would keep `User` entity (even with just PK property) and the real relationships.

Comment: You can also consider using something simpler, like dapper. If it's just a console app and an existing db, it might be easier than a full-blown Orm. Of course depends on what you want to do in your app though..

Comment: Thank you Ivan Stoev, that's the answear I was looking for - is it possible, but it's not the best way.
I would like to learn EF, that's why i dont use another ORM or ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

With your current configuration you cannot infer this join as you would have to go from `UserAddress` to `User` to `UserDetails`. You can either add a relationship between `UserAddress` and `UserDetails` to make this traversal possible or you can use the following context navigation:

`context.UserAddress.Include(x => x.User).ThenInclude(x => x.UserDetails)`

The problem is that the `User` can have many `UserDetails` thus when you include the `User` on the `UserAddress` query, there is a possibility that you would get many records.

```
Address1 -> User1 -> UserDetail1
Address1 -> User1 -> UserDetail2
```